# SystemCommandsが非活性になる

Tags: wpf, xaml

Windows7SP1(32bit), VisualStudio2013ProfessionalでWPFアプリケーションを作成しております。
対象のフレームワークは.NET Framework 4.5です。

ウインドウ右上の最大化／最小化／元に戻す／閉じる、のコマンドを標準のButtonへ実装したいと思っています。

そこで、以下のように実装しました。

```
<Window x:Class="SystemCommandsSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="target"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="120" Width="185">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="最小化" Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=target}" />
        <Button Content="元に戻す" Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=target}" />
        <Button Content="最大化" Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=target}" />
        <Button Content="閉じる" Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=target}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

上記の実装で良いと思っていたのですが、実行してみると４つのボタンが非活性の状態です。
ボタンの動作を実現するためのアドバイスを頂けると助かります。

出来ればView側（XAML）のみでこの機能は完結したいと考えています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[英語版StackOverflowの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930633/in-wpf-can-i-have-a-borderless-window-that-has-regular-minimize-maximise-and-c)を参考にしてみました。
C#側のコーディングも必要のようです。

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="120" Width="185">   
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_1" />
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_2" />
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_3" />
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_4" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="最小化" Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=target}" />
            <Button Content="元に戻す" Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=target}" />
            <Button Content="最大化" Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=target}" />
            <Button Content="閉じる" Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=target}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#の実装は、

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }
    private void CommandBinding_Executed_1(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(this);
    }
    private void CommandBinding_Executed_2(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.RestoreWindow(this);
    }
    private void CommandBinding_Executed_3(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.MaximizeWindow(this);
    }
    private void CommandBinding_Executed_4(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemCommands.CloseWindow(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: 成程。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.systemcommands(v=vs.110).aspx
に「このクラスのプロパティは RoutedCommand オブジェクトを表し、コマンドの実装ロジックを提供しません。」と書いているのをよく読んでおりませんでした…。自前の実装が必要だったのですね。
頂いた回答を参考にさせていただきます。
ありがとうございました。